# Assigning NSString to UILabel error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nsstring, uilabel

I am using CLLocationManager to try and grab my users latitude and longitude, cast them into an NSString and display them on screen in a UILabel using the following code;

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
     didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation 
            fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

     CLLocationCoordinate2D location=newLocation.coordinate;
     NSString *latLong = [NSString   stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",location.latitude,location.longitude];
     locationView.text = latLong;  
}
```

Everything compiles and runs without issue, but the UILabel 'locationView' does not get populated.  I have tested with just creating an NSString and trying that which works fine.

Any ideas where my error is?

Comment: Have you tried just `NSLog`-ing the latitude and longitude to see if they exist?

Comment: How is the locationView added to the view hierarchy? If it's an outlet, is it connected?

Comment: Are you sure that the method (locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:...) is being called? Basically test this by pixelfreak's suggestion.

Comment: @pixelfreak location is a struct so it exists and if the values "didn't" exists they would probably be 0 so it would still look something like @"0.00000,0.000000".

Comment: when i run an NSLog on latLong it does not display anything in the Log so obviously it has nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `locationView` is likely `nil` at the time of the call. You may need to store the location in an instance variable and on `viewDidLoad` set the `locationView` text there as well.

Comment: Can you advise how I can store it as an instance variable?

Comment: In the header file create a @property(retain) CLLocation *recentLocation; and store newLocation in it. When viewDidLoad occurs set the text to the string you create with recentLocation if it is not nil.

Answer (score 1):

Some things to try:

1. Make sure locationView isn't nil.
2. Make sure locationView is in the view hierarchy.
3. Make sure if locationView is an IBOutlet, that you've attached the correct object in your xib.
4. Make sure your delegate method is getting called.
5. Make sure locationView's frame isn't CGRectZero.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check latLong with

```
NSLog(@"%@", latLong);
```

How does locationView look like?

Comment: Nothing outputs to the log so obviously nothing exists in it..hhhmmm

Comment: @imperiousdev try to change it to 'NSLog(@"%f,%f",location.latitude,location.longitude);'

Answer (score 0):

Try `NSLog(@"%@",locationView);` to check if locationView is nil.

Answer (score 0):

Is it kosher to create a new variable with the same name as a parameter? Have you tried naming your coordinate variable something else?